# Why does selection get removed after a right-click on selected text to open the context menu?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, material-ui

I am using the [context menu implementation provided by Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#context-menu). It's working perfectly fine on Chrome as shown below.

**Chrome:**

[image]

But I am facing one strange issue on the Firefox browser. With Firefox and Material UI's context menu combination, when I select the text and perform a right-click on the selected text, it triggers a context menu, but it just clears out the text selection. It is reproducible on the Material UI's [official site as well](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/#context-menu).

**Firefox:**

[image]

Am I missing something with Firefox here?

Comment: This isn't the first thing I've encountered that doesn't work in firefox, `backdrop-filter`, `smooth` behavior in scrollTo function, very strictly limited `canvas-size`, `scrollWidth` not working just to name a few. I hate to admit it but firefox is slowly dying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one workaround to make the Menu component work on Firefox browser. You need to instruct the `Menu` component to behave differently as shown in following code snippet.

```
<Menu
  ...
  autoFocus={false}
  disableAutoFocus
  ...
>
```

1. `autoFocus` - If you set this prop to `false`, focus will be placed on the parent modal container. Find more details about `autoFocus` in [Menu's API section](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/menu/).
2. `disableAutoFocus` - If set to `true`, the modal will not automatically shift focus to itself when it opens and replaces it with the last focused element when it closes. Find more details about `disableAutoFocus` in [Modal's API section](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/).

With this solution, you need to take some extra consideration of accessibility.